# L2TP/IPSec VPN on macOS not routing packets trough VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I have a weird issue on my macbook pro. I configured my company VPN that uses IPSec over L2TP. I added the PSK and user credentials. I connected to the VPN and everything was working fine. However, at one point I noticed I don't have access to my email anymore, which requires me to be on VPN. I was still connected to the VPN, I typed `ifconfig` to check what's happening, and I saw the following output: `ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1200
    inet 10.78.70.3 --> 10.78.70.1 netmask 0xffffff00`

Everything seemed fine. I tried to to ping 10.78.70.1 and I got the response, however when I tried to ping the company's email server I got *request timetout*. I know the email server was working because I tried from another device. Then I typed *What is my IP* in Google search to find out if my packets are being routed trough the VPN and to my suprise I saw my own IP address, and not the company one. This problem persisted for a few days now, and I don't know what to do. I tried restarting the computer, removing the configuration and adding it once again with no results. I know the VPN is working because I connect fine fom my iphone using the same settings and same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by selecting Cisco IPSec instead of L2TP over IPSec. It seems that there is a bug with newer versions of macOS that this might happen if you select L2TP over IPSec, but if you select Cisco IPSec it works as it should.